# Force a refresh on parent component

Tags: angular

I'm working with a small datagrid in Angular 2 and i have a question about parent/child relationships between components. I have two components: `app-datagrid` and `app-add-item`. The datagrid component, in his HTML, includes the `app-add-item` component, which is composed of a button and a modal. When clicked, the button displays the modal with a form to create a new item.

All the logic is isolated and nice: the `app-add-item` component creates and handles the form, sends the form data to the service and creates a new item. However, how can i update the datagrid once its child component has finished adding a new item?

Should the `app-datagrid` component listen for an event? Should it be passed as a dependency to the child? What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could have the `app-add-item` component emit an `@Output` event to indicate an item has been added.  Then have the `app-datagrid` bind to that event - something like this:

```
<app-data-grid #dataGrid>
..
   <app-add-item (itemAdded)="dataGrid.addNewItem($event)"></app-add-item>
..
</app-data-grid>
```

Comment: Doesn't this add a pretty direct dependency between the two? Shouldn't they be isolate?

Comment: What i mean is: why the add-item component needs to know that a datagrid component is expecting stuff from it?

Comment: The add-item component doesn't know what the datagrid is expecting - it just provides an output event indicating that something has been added.  You could have a number of actions be bound to that event - e.g. add a row to the grid, display a message etc. None of these actions are defined in the add-item component.

Comment: There are a few ways for components to communicate but this is the simplest (at least for me) that would meet your requirements.
The documentation for [component communication](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) describes this under the 'Parent listens for child event' section.